# looping and union all in oracle select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table in oracle. version 9i

```
Num          count

123              1
345              4
455              3
234              2
542              1
```

I am trying to write a select query which gives me the following output.

```
123
345
345
345
345
455
455
455
234
234
542
```

Each number should be displayed its count number of times. Can this be achieved if I use functions? I am not allowed to create any temporary tables.

I understand that I have to use loops sequences and then UNION ALL but not sure how to achieve it. I tried this

```
select Num from <table> where count=1
union all
// what fits here?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done using pseudo column `LEVEL` and `Correlated Query` for repeating the num count number of times...

Try the below query

```
select num from (select distinct num,level,ROWID as RD
from table a
connect by level<= (select count from table b where a.num=b.num))
order by rd;
```

Comment: you can replace connect by level<= (select count from table b where a.num=b.num)) with connect by level<= num))

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT A.NUM
FROM Test A
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM RN FROM dual connect by level < 100) B 
ON B.rn <= A.count
order by A.NUM;
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39a59/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte ("Num", "count") 
AS 
(
    SELECT "Num", "count" FROM TableName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Num", "count" - 1  FROM cte WHERE "count" > 1
)
SELECT "Num" 
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY "Num"
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e08ca/9)

Comment: TY.I am using oracle 9i. so I am getting unsupported column aliasing.

Comment: if that's the case, see @rs. 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 11gR2 you can do it like this:

```
with t(num, i) as
(
  select num, count from tab1 union all
  select num, i-1
  from t
  where i >1
  )    
select num from t
order by num;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8788d/6)

Comment: TY.I am using oracle 9i. so I am getting unsupported column aliasing.